# What would Inversia's climate map look like?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, climate, geography

Inversia is a world conjured up by Chris Wayan that expands on the old "inverted Earth" trope.

[image]

The instructions he made were as followed [in this link](http://www.worlddreambank.org/I/INV.HTM):

1. Mark the sea level carefully.
2. Remove all the water. Store safely. We'll need it soon. *Some* of it.
3. Now mark the altitude of every point on Earth and...turn it inside out. Make every depth a height, and every height a depth.
4. Now pour seawater into the continental basins until they fill to the old coastline.

Wayans also projected that air pressure at sea level is 170% greater than Earth's, which means more heat is being stored.  This means that "sea level" is actually 2.8 kilometers (1.7 miles) above ours.  He has saved us a whole lot of trouble by giving us elevation and its legend, but it doesn't tell us much climatologically.  So with this map and the details provided above, what would the climate map of Inversia look like?

Comment: How can on pour seawater into the continental basins until they fill to the old coastline and have "sea level" is actually 2.8 kilometers (1.7 miles) above ours?

Comment: @L.Dutch You don't use all of Earth's water, if I recall correctly only about 70% goes back in, Inversia has a much smaller percentage ocean cover, they're relatively shallow and they have a very small depth range when compared to the world we live on.

Comment: Do you want to stay true to the image or do you want to keep all of earth's current water content? Depending on one or the other you may have to sacrifice a good bit of the smaller landmasses in the above image to the oceans and expand the continentally inverse oceans a little.

Answer (score 4):

Some things are immediately apparent:

- The temperature gradient between the equator and poles is going to be brutal, there are no circulating ocean currents to carry heat away from the tropics and warm the poles.
- Very little of the new continents is far from a major body of water so "continental climate" is a thing of the past.
- There are going to be some, literally impossibly (they will collapse spectacularly under their own weight), tall mountain chains closer to the edge of the sea than anything we see on Earth, those are going to create some absolute rain shadows and 100% capture orographic rainfall zones, we don't see that on Earth, anywhere, the closest we have is the Atacama desert.
- Much of the continental area is also going to be far higher above sea level, so average rainfall will often be lower. This will slow erosion and the carbonate/silicate rock cycle that contributes to the stability of atmospheric chemistry.
- Due to the relatively small ocean basins wave heights are going to be lower, wave trains are going to have less energy, and tides are going to be smaller, this means that coastal erosion will also be slowed reducing the availability of ocean nutrients, that's going to cut down plankton blooms and effect atmospheric oxygen levels.